# Save jmeter Http request's response data in string java code

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I am developing application in which user will give URL of the page based on that HTTP sampler request will be  send and response is displayed. Please suggest me proper way for doing this.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate your question. Given [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle I would suggest designing your test like:

- [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

  - [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request): Path: `${__P(url,)}`

    - [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor): Script: `System.out.println(new String(data));`

and saving it as i.e. `test.jmx`

So if you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode like](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode):

```
jmeter -Jurl=http://your.url.here -n -t example.jmx
```

you will be able to see response in the same command line.

If you're developing your application in Java - here's [JMeter API reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/)